# How do I remove this plate holder from the Ecosport? Drill, special tool or?

Tags: ford, tools, bolts, accessories

There are **three** bolt? -like fasteners.

Looking at the photo, notice the three large indentations.

Each large indentation has an unusual rivet ? like fastener

Look at the close-ups to see the fasteners.

As far as I can determine, there's no access to behind.

Photos including closeup below, TY.

[image]

(Note - the **four** small holes in the plastic are nothing, that's just where you attach the license plate to this holder. The problem is the three large openings where this holder is attached to my bumper.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There were three screws, one in each of the holes?

Comment: Images of a new plate holder show 4 stubs with holes in there, behind where the 4 artifacts are on picture 1. Could not find definitively if screws are there. If they are, that's 4 screws from behind. If not this is a pure push on situation held on with the 3 main screws and you can just pull off. Try pry gently with long thin screw driver, where the 4 artifacts are and see of you can get movement or if there are screws there

Comment: hi @Chris I added more text in the question to explain more clearly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are plastic expanding rivets with the inner part broken off.  If you use a small punch you should be able to pop the inner portion out the back and then pull the outer portion out with a pick or small screwdriver.

Similar to these:

[image]

Comment: BRILLIANT !!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest if there were screws, one in each of the holes and you removed them, and now it still doesn't want to come off, there is some type of double sided tape further securing it to the bumper. If you are just trying to get rid of the thing, apply some pressure and pull it off. Don't be afraid of it. If you need to pull it off and subsequently put it back after you're done, then just don't get malevolent with it, but additional force is what is needed here. Give it a nice easy sustained pull and I bet you'll find it will start pulling away from the bumper without damaging anything.

Comment: ah, there were no screws.  did you see the photos? (perhaps I didn't post them right.)  it's some sort of rivet? or similar fastener. see fourth photo ...

Comment: There are videos on this, you just pry the rivets out. Did not realize this was the same with the talk of screws

Comment: @Fattie - My apologies as it *looks like* there were screws there which were removed. Your description was not clear to me, so as I stated ... I went out on a limb. Be that as it may, my suggestion to you does not change, except as what Chris has thrown into the mix.

Comment: never a need to apologize on a manly car list!  :)  yes, it does not peel off (as with tape).  it is very clearly anchored by the three mystery fasteners. (if you give it a tug, you can clearly feel the three spots where the three fasteners are)

Comment: Seems the recommendations for this is to drill the fasteners out and remove with pliers. Why does this simple thing need to be so hard and destructive? ...

Comment: @Chris - No flippin lie ... If you'd like to put that as an answer and show your source, not only will I delete my answer, I'll uptick yours as well.

Comment: Wish I could state a source, but it was from a splat of youtube searches

Comment: @Chris - Post it anyways. Better to state sources, but much, much worse to not have the knowledge here.